# How to extract single Type from a union?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

assuming I have this type:

`type FooArray = IFoo[] | number[]  | undefined`

is it possible to extract just `IFoo` from this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Since [TypeScript 2.8 supports conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) you can do:

```
interface IFoo { 
    name: string
}

type FooArray = IFoo[] | number[] | undefined

type FindType<TWhere> = TWhere extends (infer U)[] ? (U extends object ? U : never) : never

type FoundType = FindType<FooArray> // FoundType == IFoo
```

Note that the `U extends object ? U : never` is required so that `number` is not matched.

Answer (score 3):

For Completeness `Exclude` along with a type query can also be used resulting in something pretty readable

```
interface IFoo { 
    name: string
}

type FooArray = IFoo[] | number[]  | undefined

type ArrayValues = Exclude<FooArray, undefined>[number] // IFoo | number

type IFooExtracted = Exclude<ArrayValues, number> // IFoo
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) which was introduced in [TypeScript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) is made to extract types from Unions.

```
type FooArray = IFoo[] | number[] | undefined;
type Result = Extract<FooArray, IFoo[]>[number]; // type Result = IFoo
```

---

The [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) (`[number]`) helps us extracting the array item value. It essentially does the same as `T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never`.